# Verbatim in plain-format with XeTeX

Tags: xetex, verbatim, plain-tex

*(I'm aware there has been a similar question before, but this one has a twist)*

I wanted a verbatim macro to use which would use an unlikely character as an end-of-verbatim -marker (unlikely as in it would be unlikely to be included in the text that would become verbatim), and looked up a couple of suggestions from Appendix D of *The TeXbook*, until something caught my eye:

> Another approach is to keep one character untouchable. For example, it’s possible to define things so that `\verbatim⟨char⟩⟨text⟩⟨char⟩` will typeset the `⟨text⟩` verbatim, where the `⟨text⟩` is not supposed to contain any occurrences of the repeated delimiter `⟨char⟩`:
>
> ```
> \def\verbatim{\begingroup\setupverbatim\doverbatim}
> \def\doverbatim#1{\def\next##1#1{##1\endgroup}\next}
> ```

Now, combining this with XeTeX would allow me to use a character from the wide, wide Unicode range as the end-marker. (Based on the finding that I can do eg. `\def\ﬁ{foo}`, and it works.)

Alas, adding to the above the previously mentioned macros from Appendix D:

> ```
> \def\setupverbatim{\tt\def\par{\leavevmode\endgraf} \catcode`\`=\active
>    \obeylines\uncatcodespecials\obeyspaces}
> \def\uncatcodespecials{\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials}
> ```

and trying it out (the ﬁ -character is the Unicode fi-ligature),

```
\verbatim ﬁ |\%_^foo{\it bar}
baz
ﬁ
\bye
```

gives me an error about `Missing $`, which means there is something not working with the `\verbatim` macro. I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the space character after `\verbatim`.

After you change the catcode of the space character, it's not considered space anymore. Consider the output of

```
\def\a#1\relax{`#1'}
\def\b{\catcode`\ =12 \a}

\a \relax

\b \relax

\bye
```

[image]

Thus, your example only typesets `ﬁ` in verbatim mode, and returns to normal after encountering the second space after `ﬁ`.

It follows that you need to have a delimiter character *immediately* after `\verbatim`. Therefore its catcode can't be "letter", because otherwise it will be taken as a part of the control sequence name.

Comment: One should note that the space after `\verbatim` terminates the scanning for the control sequence name, but it's not tokenized right away, because after a control sequence name TeX must enter "skipping blanks state"; therefore the space is effectively read after `\verbatim` has been expanded and `\setupverbatim` has changed the category code of the space.

Comment: Oooh, the catcode change! I assume every char (outside the chars TeX knows) has a catcode of letter in the eyes of XeTeX, then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following codes defines `\verb` command:

```
\catcode`\@=11%
\def\verb{\expandafter\verb@make\string}%
\def\verb@make#1{\begingroup\tt%
  \let\verb@delim=#1%  Save the delimiter.
  \def\verb@print##1{%
    \if##1\verb@delim% If we found the end delimiter, end the group.
      \def\verb@print{\def\verb@print{}\endgroup}%
    \else%
      ##1% Print the char
    \fi%
    \expandafter\verb@print\string% Continue reading the next char.
  }%
  \expandafter\verb@print\string% Start reading.
}%
\catcode`\@=12%
```

Some examples:

```
\verb|{$x^y{}$\abc}|

\verb!{$x^y{}$\abc}!

\verb~${x^y{}$\abc}~
```

All the above produces verbatim `${x^y{}$\abc}`.

Comment: It doesn't respect spaces, though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the space following `\verbatim`, as found out by Andrey. One should note that the space after `\verbatim` terminates the scanning for the control sequence name, but it's not tokenized right away, because after a control sequence name TeX must enter "skipping blanks state"; therefore the space is effectively read after `\verbatim` has been expanded and `\setupverbatim` has changed the category code of the space.

If you don't want to have a limitation on what characters can delimit the verbatim snippet, it's possible to improve `\doverbatim`:

```
\def\doverbatim#1{%
  \def\next{#1}%
  \ifx\next\activespacemacro
     \expandafter\doverbatim
  \else
    \def\next##1#1{##1\endgroup}%
    \expandafter\next
  \fi}
{\obeyspaces\gdef\activespacemacro{ }}
```

End-of-line can't be used as a delimiter (it would be possible to add another test for it). Any number of spaces can follow `\verbatim`.

It's curious to understand why your code gave that error, but also easy: the space after `ﬁ` made `\verbatim` terminate its effect, typesetting as verbatim just the `ﬁ`.